# My Emulator crashes every time I try to run my code

Tags: android, debugging, crash, emulation, logcat

I have looked around online for similar threads, but none have been helpful.

I'm trying to do the SIMPLE task of making onClick button sounds. I worked for hours on end trying to get the code right, and as soon as it looks like it's going to work, it won't even run.

It says, "Unfortunately, Attempt has stopped." and my LogCat file opens with 200+ error messages that make no sense.

Could you look at my code and tell me what the problem is? Thank you.

```
package com.example.attempt;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SoundEffectConstants;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.muteButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

        AudioManager audioManager =
                (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);




    public void onClick(View v) {
        audioManager.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, the Emulator doesn't handle the AudioManager very well. And, like the first answer shows, you're instancing it at the wrong time. Posting the logcat would help as well. (you might have Security Exceptions if you haven't added the correct permissions to your manifest)

Comment: You need to post your layout as well (the xml). You're apparently trying to use a TextView as a Button as well...

Answer (score 5):

initialize `AudioManager` audioManager instance inside `onCreate` method as :

```
   AudioManager audioManager;  //<<<< declare here...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.muteButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

         /// initialize here
        audioManager =
                (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    }
```

Comment: +1 Yes, this is the correct answer!! Since @user83676 is initializing AudioManager before oncreate as instance variable, it won't work. Android doesn't allow system services before onCreate.

Comment: that makes sense, but I'm still getting a ton of error messages when I run it. 
300+ in the LogCat file! :(

Comment: @user83676 : if u are still getting error then plz add LogCat file contains with question

Comment: @user83676 : Thanks use this code http://pastebin.com/zsDCq91d bez i think u are sill doing in wrong way

Comment: Added relevant section of the logcat. It shows it's the correct answer (thus far). However, the latest lines show you have a different problem somewhere else. For which you probably need to open a new question.

Comment: well what is the different problem!?

Comment: You need to post your layout as well (the xml). You're apparently trying to use a TextView as a Button as well...

Comment: @user83676 : @ DigCamara is also right just change `<TextView .../>` in xml layout to `<Button ... />` because you are trying to cast an TextView to Button

Comment: I'm trying to find my xml but I accidentally closed it and I can't reopen it! AAHhhhhh!

Comment: EOIRGFHS)IORG 

So guess what, guys? I deleted the text view.
Now it runs. 

BUT THE CLICK SOUND STILL DOESN'T WORK.

Comment: yeah. Told you the Emulator isn't very good with the AudioManager.

Comment: ... don't you have a device to test it on? (BTW... THE HUMANITY? Bit melodramatic for a friday ain't it?)

Answer (score 1):

this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.muteButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

    AudioManager audioManager =
            (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Change it to

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 AudioManager audioManager =
                (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.muteButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: I copy-pasted in what you did, but it didn't work! It is still crashing :(

Comment: You need to declare audioManager as a member variable so that the onClick has access to it. This code won't work as-is.

Comment: I started coding in java like a week ago, I have no idea what is going on!! haha. 
How do I do that?